# Joomla show sub category title on category blog page

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, subcategories

I can't believe this isn't possible by default in Joomla core?!

I have a Category called Projects and a sub category called Previous Projects. What I want to do is display thumbnails/links for each on a category blog page like so:

PROJECTS

IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE

IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE

---

PREVIOUS PROJECTS

IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE

ETC...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by creating a module, and assign it on the menu item you want to.

Let's say you have menu item called Projects which type is category blog from Project category. Then just create a module from the extensions tab with certain type you prefer, there are Article Category, Article categories, Article Newsflash, etc, choose source from Previous Project Category then assign it on Project menu item,and place the module on any position you like.

Comment: I cant believe that it has to be so long winded. All they need is an option in the blog category to include sub category title and the logic in the code to insert that break point. Thanks Adadion :-D