# Show articles from category and all it's subcategories on homepage

Tags: menu

My homepage is currently only showing blog posts of one category.

Under Category Manager I have a category called "Homepage blog", with several sub-categories (all using Homepage blog" as the parent).

Under the Menu Manager I have a Menu called "Home". It has a Menu Item Type of "Articles » Category Blog". When I open this I see that under Required Settings it has the Category of "Homepage Blog". Further options I've set include: 
Category Options: Subcategory Levels: All
Blog Layout Options: Include Subcategories: All
Details: Default Page: Yes
Template Type: - Use Default -

If I create a brand new Menu item of the type Category List, and set options to show "Homepage blog" category and all sub-categories, it again only shows items in the parent category.

I'm on Joomla 2.5 using Nano 2 Theme from YooTheme.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Let me clear, do you want a category blog menu item that can show some articles in it's sub category also? If so, see this http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15686/joomla-show-sub-category-title-on-category-blog-page/15687#15687

Comment: I actually found my answer on another forum. Here is a link to the solution: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=3378390

Comment: Great, actually, you can answer you own question, and mark it as accepted answer yourself. It would be useful in case someone having this exact problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found my answer on another forum. Here is a link to the solution: [Articles from multiple categories showing on homepage](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=3378390)

> If you set the Category Sort Order=No Order, the articles will be sorted in the Article Sort Order regardless of which category it belongs to. i.e you will have your most recent articles first.
>
> If set to a Category Sort Order, all articles in the category that are sorted first will be shown before the next category.
>
> As the Order is set to use Global, you have to enter the Global Settings (Options Button in Article Manager) to see what is set.
> "

Comment: Hi @Maureen and welcome to JSE. Please refrain of posting link-only answers, because links could go down. Try to copy solution or it's portion, into your answer directly.